# Can Some one explain why I get these output?

Tags: c, casting, unsigned

I am new to c.

My Question.

> Why do some numbers end up negative when the value was positive?

Comment: This is why: [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Can also explain char as a decimal?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Also, You can post answers too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation for the output you are seeing.
1000 in binary is 1111101000 (10 bits) and is stored in an `int` (signed 32 bits)

When you cast that to an `unsigned char` (that has 8 bits), the top bits get "cut off".

So you get: `11101000` which is `232` in decimal.

As a (signed) char, the bits get interpreted as a negative number because the first (sign) bit is set, which in this case is -24.

When you remove the sign bit, `1101000` = `104`

The "value" of the MSB is 128, so your computer does `104 - 128 = -24`.

(See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

A long has the same or more bits as an int so the value does not change.